# How to deploy Spring MVC with Mysql DB on Heroku

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, heroku

Could any one help to deploy web app hosted at bitbucket or githup to heroku
The project based on Spring MVC, Hibernate

Comment: There is existing tutorial on heroku but its using postgres sql. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate

Comment: yes, I read it but doesn't give complete information

Comment: Post what problem you are facing then..

Answer (score 2):

Heroku does not directly support MySQL you can either convert your MySQL database over to PostgreSQL database

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

or host it on a different provider.

Heroku provides the cleardb addon for this purpose:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb

or you can use a service like amazon RDS:

http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

I found converting the data to PostgreSQL even with the ruby plug in they suggest to be a complete pain in the butt and wouldn't recommend it unless you need to save a bunch of data you already have. (I had already been planning on switching to PostgreSQL so it wasn't a huge deal for me) If you don't have data to save and are willing to make the switch its still not super easy but it will be a bit more straight forward since you are using Hibernate.

If your project is built with Maven all you need to do is pull your code from bit bucket then push it to Heroku, remember to add the the "Proc" file Heroku uses to tell what it should execute once the time comes. This process is described here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

If you don't use maven you can push a war file directly:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

As for Spring, as long as you include all the relevant packages in your maven POM or War, you should be fine and it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your comment, Secondly Regarding to commit from githup\bitbucket to Heroku the commend return with can't read access problem ? could you show how to commit with commands sample

Comment: This seems a little out of the scope of the question, it would probably be better if you re-post what you are seeing on the command line as another question and topic. You are also more likely to get responses from more people. (Leave a link here to your new question as a comment if you like)

Answer (score 0):

**I Found It** You Can perform that by host your DB on external hosting and just deploy EAR | WAR on Heroku
But be sure that DB is live before deploy your Ear.